# Using Mysql to store articles as Wordpress does

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, codeigniter

I am looking for a way to store article in database in the same format as it would appear on the website. Could anyone here kindly explain how to store the entire article in database and later display the same on web? I suppose I need some mechanism to accomplish this. But I couldn't find any solution for the past 4 days despite extensive searching all over. Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to store? Dynamic content provided by users?

Comment: as i understand you want to store code such as css link files ex bootstap cdn. `HTML file` as <a><b>etc in mysql database

Comment: question unclear, no examples or anything for referecne included

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas.I want to store the web pages For example, my application would have pages similar to w3schools.com/css/default.asp. All I want to do is to store the contents including sample code snippets on the page, and later fetch them to display on the pages.

Comment: Pavan and Raghubendra, I just explained in a comment above what exactly I am looking to accomplish. Please see if that helps you understand the task.

Comment: Hi Kirk, Thanks for the response. I am using codeigniter. I have PHP scripts in the file system which I want to store in database. I suppose knowing how stack overflow maintains the web page contents would help me find the solution.

Comment: You don't store php in the database only the HTML component (comments, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing html in a database is easy enough, but trying to store whole webpages is not the right way to do it...

Many WYSIWYG editors send html through for you to store, depending on your requirements typically you would store these in a VARCHAR to TEXT column in your (MySQL) database.

Simply insert the data into your database with a normal INSERT statement.

Comment: Thanks Brian. great answer. my web page will allow users to add the comments the way stack overflow does. How do go about doing this?

Comment: CKEditor is one such package that allows this, I suggest looking at it. stackoverflow uses WMD but it is not publicly available (from my knowledge) an open branch is here (https://github.com/openlibrary/wmd). Have a google search of html WYSIWYG editors, each has their own ways of doing things but at the end of the day their result will be in an <input> field which you can send/get through POST data to add to your database.

Comment: Hi Brian, your answers are helping me understand things. Yet, I couldn't get to a solution of my issue. i would like you to share a couple of your ideas on how to main a page like w3schools.com/css/default.asp using database. Kindly share your views. Thanks

Comment: @user7321290 most of those pages are static, very little would be stored in the database, especially their content. Stack overflow is a place people can help you with your code issues. Not tell you how to build a site

Comment: Yes, I certainly understand the scope of stackoverflow which I respect always. My only issue is with the ability to store code snippets in database and fetch them to display on the pages..